# Pexels API HTTP Authorization Header

Tags: api, authorization

I just started learning about APIs and I am trying to use the pexels API found here: https://www.pexels.com/api/

I have gotten the API Key, however I am not sure where to put my API key at. 
I want the result to display JSON.

When I run this code on bash it works, however, I am not sure how to do it inside javascript.

```
curl -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY" "http://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people"
```

I am running express and request.
This is my code.

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
app.set("view engine","ejs");

var url = "http://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=example+query&per_page=15&page=1";
   request(url, function(error,response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log(body);
      } 
   });

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
   console.log("server is running!"); 
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am new to this and tried to Google for an answer but couldn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add header to make api calls,

The code goes this way,

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
app.set("view engine","ejs");
var data = {
   url : "http://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=example+query&per_page=15&page=1",
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Your-Api-Key'
   } 
}
request(data, function(error,response, body){
 if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      console.log(body);
  }
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
  console.log("server is running!"); 
});
```